# How to add new element to pandas.DataFrame column which is list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` like this:

```
id       count        fruit_list
---------------------------------------
0        42           [orange, apple]
1        57           [lemon]
2        86           [kiwi]
3        33           [pineapple, pear]
4        11           [apple, lemon]
...
```

I need to add new string to `fruit_list` in every row. Let's say the string is `banana`, so I need to end with `DataFrame` like this:

```
id       count        fruit_list
---------------------------------------
0        42           [orange, apple, banana]
1        57           [lemon, banana]
2        86           [kiwi, banana]
3        33           [pineapple, pear, banana]
4        11           [apple, lemon, banana]
...
```

How can I do this most easily please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `apply`:

```
df['fruit_list'] = df['fruit_list'].apply(lambda x: x + ['banana'])
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'count': [42, 57], 
                   'fruit_list': [['orange', 'apple'], ['lemon']], 
                   'id': [0, 1]}).reindex_axis(['id','count','fruit_list'], 1)
print (df)
   id  count       fruit_list
0   0     42  [orange, apple]
1   1     57          [lemon]

df['fruit_list'] = df['fruit_list'].apply(lambda x: x + ['banana'])
print (df)
   id  count               fruit_list
0   0     42  [orange, apple, banana]
1   1     57          [lemon, banana]
```

Comment: @SRingne - Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @jezrael. Maybe it's worth a different question, but how could I add different fruit to `fruit_list` column in every row, e.g. I have predefined set `(fruit1, fruit2...fruitN)` and I want to append `fruit1` to `row1['tag']`, `fruit2` to `row2['tag']` ... `fruitN` to `rowN['tag']` etc...

Comment: Unfortunately I am now on phone only, I think you can post new question.