# How to combine two pandas.DataFrames which have lists as columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am asking a questions similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43386043/how-to-add-new-element-to-pandas-dataframe-column-which-is-list) but I need something a bit different. I have two `pandas.DataFrames` and I need to merge them.

Here is first `df_1`:

```
id       attr         fruit_list
---------------------------------------
0        42           [orange, apple]
1        57           [lemon]
2        86           [kiwi]
3        33           [pineapple, pear]
4        11           [apple, lemon]
```

and here is second `df_2`:

```
id     fruit_list
--------------------------------------
0      [fruit1,]
1      [fruit4, fruit2]
2      [fruit2, fruit8]
3      [fruit3,]
4      [fruit3,]
```

I need to merge those two `DataFrames` to get output like this:

```
id       attr         fruit_list
---------------------------------------------
0        42           [orange, apple, fruit1]
1        57           [lemon, fruit4, fruit2]
2        86           [kiwi, fruit2, fruit8]
3        33           [pineapple, pear, fruit3]
4        11           [apple, lemon, fruit3]
```

How can I achieve this please? I have looked at [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) but I couldn't figure out a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the id matches in order, you can add the two columns:

```
df1.fruit_list = df1.fruit_list + df2.fruit_list
df1
```

[image]

Or if need to merge on `id` column, you can merge, and then add the `fruit_list` columns:

```
(df1.merge(df2, on = "id")
 .assign(fruit_list = lambda x: x.fruit_list_x + x.fruit_list_y)
 .drop(["fruit_list_x", "fruit_list_y"], 1))
```

[image]